# RxJS: forkJoin mergeMap

Tags: rxjs

I'm trying to make multiple http requests and get returned data in one object.

```
const pagesToFetch = [2,3]
const request$ = forkJoin(
  from(pagesToFetch)
    .pipe(
      mergeMap(page => this.mockRemoteData(page)),
    )
)
```

mockRemoteData() return a simple Promise.
After first Observable emits (the once created from first entry of pagesToFetch  the request$ is completed, second value in not included. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can turn each value in `pagesToFetch` into an Observable and then wait until all of them complete:

```
const observables = pagesToFetch.map(page => this.mockRemoteData(page));

forkJoin(observables)
  .subscribe(...);
```

Or in case it's not that simple and you need `pagesToFetch` to be an Observable to collect urls first you could use for example this:

```
from(pagesToFetch)
  .pipe(
    toArray(),
    mergeMap(pages => {
      const observables = pages.map(page => this.mockRemoteData(page));
      return forkJoin(observables);
    }),
  )
  .subscribe(...);
```

Comment: that's right, I get rid of mergeMap and it's working, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the below sample format...

```
Observable.forkJoin(
   URL 1,
   URL 2
 ).subscribe((responses) => {
   console.log(responses[0]);
   console.log(responses[1]); 
 },
  error => {console.log(error)}
 );
```